# GroupBy if column values are equal and aggregate with sum a dataset

Tags: apache-spark

It is all in the title : i have a dataset with multiple columns which i want to `groupBy` with some of its columns (if the values in those columns are equal then group the distinct rows and aggregate sum for each), simply put i want to calculate the frequencies of distinct rows having with respect to certain columns (in the below example those columns are `col0` & `col1`) i was thinking something like this would do it :

```
dF.select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4").withColumn("sums", sum("col1").over(Window.groupBy("col0", "col1")))
```

But does this `groupBy` guarantee that the grouped rows have equal columns values in `col0` & `col1` ?

Comment: I'm confused about what the output should look like. Can you add a sample of the input DataSet (or DataFrame) and the desired output that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The output should be a dataset where certain column are aggregated and summed as described in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Spark's Java docs, `Window` class does not appear to have a `groupBy` method (as seen [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html)) so we have to resort to standard SQL-like methods implemented on `dF`, such as `where` and `groupBy`.

In order to keep the rest of the columns that are seemingly unaffected from the `groupBy` process, we need to collect their values as lists (or sets, if we just want the distinct values of the grouped rows' columns) by using [collect_list()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list-java.lang.String-) (or respectively, [collect_set()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_set-java.lang.String-)).

The grouping and renaming of the other columns could look like this (we rename the now-list of other columns `_3`, `_4`, `_5` with the same name for the sake of cohesion):

```
dF.where("_1 == _2")
          .groupBy("_1", "_2")
          .agg(collect_list("_3").as("_3"),
              collect_list("_4").as("_4"),
              collect_list("_5").as("_5"),
              sum("_1").as("sums"))
          .show()
```

So if we take the following DataSet as input:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| _5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 40| 40|  7|  9|  1|
| 41| 50|  1|  2|  1|
| 20| 20|  3| 15|  1|
| 40| 40|  3| 11|  1|
| 12| 25|  4|  9|  1|
|  6| 15|  5|  6|  1|
| 20| 20|  2| 25|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The output will look like this:

```
+---+---+------+--------+------+----+
| _1| _2|    _3|      _4|    _5|sums|
+---+---+------+--------+------+----+
| 40| 40|[7, 3]| [9, 11]|[1, 1]|  80|
| 20| 20|[3, 2]|[15, 25]|[1, 1]|  40|
+---+---+------+--------+------+----+
```

Of course, you can change the name of the columns to what you have as your input.